# Get a text from a binary vector

Tags: c++, string, binary

I have a

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
```

which contains a binary read file.

If I write it to

```
std::ofstream outputFile("file", std::ios_base::binary);
```

I'll see a regular text in it. Then I can read it into std::string which will conatain the text.
Is it possible to copy vector directly to string with the same result?

Comment: Yes, `std::string s(data.begin(), data.end());` Or if you already have a string: `s.assign(data.begin(), data.end());`

Answer (score 1):

Use the 6th form of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)'s constructor:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> data{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    std::string str(data.begin(), data.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo here](http://cpp.sh/6rzf)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/.

Use `std::String s(data.begin(), data.end());`.